# Generating edmx file for ef6(entity framework) outside of vs2013

Tags: entity-framework, edmgen

We can generate edmx from database for ef4 using edmgen tool, for ef6 edmx format is changed to v3. Does anybody know how to generate edmx file from database for ef6 outside of visual studio 2013?

Comment: Do you have any news?